# Is there a way to get Github pull requests notifications on Microsoft teams?

Tags: github, notifications, microsoft-teams

I'm looking for a way to get Github pull requests notifications on Microsoft teams. I've been using the official github Slack bot, and the pull reminders (formerly pull panda) functionality for quite a while now, and I'm sorely missing these features with MS teams. Anyone would know a good SaaS and/or opensource product for this use case?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) like [Microsoft Teams (Generic)](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/microsoft-teams-generic)

> a GitHub Actions that sends a message to a given channel in Microsoft Teams, with the most generic way.

That way, you can trigger a message [on pull-request](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) (GitHub workflow syntax)